# Is there any possibility to connect to a Amazon hosted MySQL database from a Google App Engine hosted application?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

I wonder if there are any possibilities to connecting to an Amazon hosted MySQL database via a Google App Engine hosted application.

Everything I've found so far indicates that I can connect to googles cloud SQL
[Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/)

Thank you for any ideas and help!

Comment: you mean use it as a db or just open socket connection for short period of time?

Comment: Using it as an db for the application

Comment: but why? do you understand that it's different datacenters so even if you'll be able to do that your app will be unreliable because of huge latency and frequent connection drops?

Comment: So you would suggest to either way use the GOA with the Googles Cloud SQL or host the application and database at Amazon?

Comment: I suggest that db and app should be in same datacenter, ideally on same machine

Comment: It should certainly be feasible to connect to any DB hosted per http://aws.amazon.com/rds/ , from a GAE app just as from about any other app wherever hosted.  Latency and total costs may indeed be high, but I don't understand @IgorArtamonov's worries about reliability -- if you can afford high latency and substantial $$$ impacts (as both services charge for heavy traffic you impose between them) reliability should not be a worry, any more than with any other remotely hosted DB, which isn't anything weird in these days of 100's-of-GBs optical fiber networks!-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use GAE's Remote API to connect to an AppScale deployment backed by MySQL running on AWS and store data or replicate it.

You can find instructions on how to configure your app to use Remote API [here](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Viewing-Data-in-AppScale-%28remote_api%29).

There are also [instructions](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/FAQs#how-can-i-deploy-my-app-with-mysql-cloudsql-on-appscale) on running AppScale with MySQL.